# R error in lme function: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 3)

Tags: r, nlme

I'm running linear mixed model in nlme package.

```
control <- lmeControl(maxIter=100,opt = c("optim"))
lme(response ~ 0+factorA+covariate,random=~1|factorB,
               weights=varIdent(form= ~1|factorA),control=control),
```

And, it come an error as following.

```
Error in logLik.reStruct(object, conLin) :NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 3)
```

Is it the same as the convergence error? or others?

Thanks

Comment: sorry, but there's not nearly enough information provided to answer the question.  Please post a reproducible example if possible ( http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ), and at the very least more information on context.

Comment: I edit my original question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite an answer, but the formatting would be horrible in a comment.  (Will delete or edit later if the question gets resolved.)

I can't reproduce, so far.  Here is a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(101)
d <- data.frame(covariate=runif(500),response=rnorm(500),
                factorA=factor(sample(1:5,size=500,replace=TRUE)),
                factorB=factor(sample(1:5,size=500,replace=TRUE)))
library("nlme")
control <- lmeControl(maxIter=100,opt = c("optim"))
m1 <- lme(response ~ 0+factorA+covariate,random=~1|factorB,
          weights=varIdent(form= ~1|factorA),control=control,
          data=d)
```

Since this works, it's hard to go farther.

It would be best if you can [provide a reproducible example](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000).  Short of that, you can debug/help debug by setting `options(error=recover)` or `debug(nlme:::logLik.reStruct)`.  Once you get into the browser, you can try commands like

```
ls()
str(object)
str(conLin)
dput(object)
dput(conLin)
```

and provide the results as appropriate.